# google maps marker clusterer not working in IE7 & IE8 due to an 'is null or not an object' error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

[I have a google Map](http://expertforum.ro/extra/harta-bugetelor/primarii.html) (js api v3) + marker clusterer which doesn't display in Internet Explorer 7 & 8 - I get the classical js error:

> Message: 'addresses[...].lt' is null or not an object

On the other hand, [this other example](http://expertforum.ro/extra/harta-bugetelor/judete.html) which uses a very similar json file, but doesn't use marker clusterer - displays the same error, but renders the markers on the map.

So I'm not even sure it's .json syntax error, rather something that bothers the marker clusterer instance, but I have no idea what

Comment: there is a trailing comma in addresses, remove it

Comment: thank you sir!, for taking time to adress the dumb :)